# Define command that either does \kill or \textcolor

Tags: color, text-manipulation

I have some paragraphs in my thesis, that will stay in there until just before it is finished. They should be marked as non-important to my supervisor. Then I'd like to remove those paragraphs all at once.

Instead of `\kill` I defined the command `\rem`, which is also good for more than one line.

In the document this looks like this:

```
Blah blah, very important.
\remm{As we all know, the sky is blue.}
Blah blah, also important.
```

In my header (above `\begin{document}`) I want to do something like this:

```
%current setting
\def\remm{\textcolor[rgb]{0.3,0.3,0.3}}
%\def\remm{\rem} 
%final setting
%\def\remm{\textcolor[rgb]{0.3,0.3,0.3}}
\def\remm{\rem}
```

Yet, `\textcolor{...}` changes the vertical spacing of my document, which is not acceptable.

Do you have any ideas? I can also imagine to put a vertical line along those unimportant paragraphs or something similar.

The minimal example is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\rem}[1]{}
\def\remm{\textcolor[rgb]{0.3,0.3,0.3}}
%\def\remm{\rem}

\begin{document}
Blah blah, very important.
\remm{
As we all know, the sky is blue.

more paragraphs following
}
Blah blah, also important.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\textcolor` would not change the spacing if you always use it as `\remmm{text here...`  If you use it as you show then ypu have (in one case) a spurious paragraph and (in the other) spurious horizontal white space that will come or go depending on which definition you use

Comment: I just edited my example: There can be more than one paragraph I want to remove, so `\textcolor` ruins my vertical spacing

Comment: No If you put multiple paragraphs into `\textcolor` you get an _error_ after any error you should not comment on the typographical output, TeX does not try to make a sensible pdf after an error, its recovery action is just intended to allow further debugging not to make sensible output.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a command that doesn't leave traces behind it if disabled, you should do

```
\makeatletter
% final setting
%\newcommand{\remm}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\makeatother
% draft setting
\newcommand{\remm}[1]{%
  \begingroup % don't make color leak out
  \leavevmode % be sure to be in horizontal mode
  \color[rgb]{0.3,0.3,0.3}% set the color
  #1% set the text
  \endgroup‌ % end the group
}
```

Comment: Yeah but this adds vertical spaces again, since I use it on my Theorems and Definitions (`\newtheoremstyle` etc.)

Comment: @reinbot Without knowing your use cases, only generic answers can be given. However, why bothering, since you'll use it only in draft versions?

Comment: @reinbot why do you want to colour `\newtheoremstyle` ??

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue:

```
\newcommand{\remm}[1]{}%final setting
\newcommand{\remm}[1]{\color[rgb]{0.3,0.3,0.3}#1\color{black}} %current setting
```

Comment: Why not `\newcommand{\remm}[1]{\begingroup\leavevmode\color[rgb]{0.3,0.3,0.3}#1\endgroup}`?

Comment: Unlike `\textcolor` or the version @egreg suggests in the comment using `\color` in that way _will_ affect spacing. See the color package documentation for advice on using `\textcolor` rather than `\color` to avoid bad spacing effects.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I did not know that!  Who would have thought that `\color` would affect spacing?  I guess I'll have to read the documentation, after all.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the fact that you have gone so long without noticing that `\special` can affect spacing is testament care with which latex tries to put them in safe places. I wonder who wrote that code?

Comment: David, You are indeed `\special` in my book `:^)`.  And I see mention of it in the footnote on page 7 of `grfguide.pdf`.